# Best practice for beginners to gain weight

Tags: weight-gain, push-ups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

I'm doing some basic workout i.e. push-ups for approximately, last 9 months. I have gained 7 kilograms during that period. I also joined a gym 5 months ago but due to some circumstances I couldn't continue, but I did not stop doing push-ups at home. I want to gain more weight, muscle and strength. What should I do?

I consider myself a beginner because I have a very little knowledge of workout practices and all those things.

Currently my push-ups workout includes 5 sets of 30 reps.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you willing to join a gym again or do you prefer to do your exercises at home?

Comment: I prefer to do exercise at home but wouldn't mind if joining a gym will be more beneficial.

Comment: [This answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) to an essentially identical question should help.

Comment: I think this question can be closed as a duplicate unless it is made more specific. In the current form all answers from the linked question will work for this one, too.

Comment: The user has asked nearly the [same question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/7718/3941) before.

Comment: @Informaficker I would be okay with merging this question with this user's other identical question, but this question is not the same as the one I linked to IMO.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann I just think that this question is too unspecific too receive answers that differ from the other questions.

Comment: The only thing that happens here is the combination of "how do I get big" and "I have no idea what exercises to do, please help". I am sure that we already have questions that answer both questions. If they don't @PawanSharma has to be more specific why they didn't.

Comment: @Informaficker Good point. Pawan, could you be more specific about what you need? General advice on how to gain size and strength is in [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771), which I linked to above. Unless you are more specific than "how do I gain size and strength, this question is a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people believe that working out is the only way to gain weight. This isn't true. While working out in general is effective for gaining muscle, eating is probably gonna be about 75% of what will help you gain weight. Assuming you're an ectomorph, you're going to want to eat loads of calories. the general rule of thumb I found is your weight (in lbs) * 20 = your daily  calorie intake. Make sure you are eating healthy fats and getting as much protein as you can (about 40% of the calories should be protein).

As far as exercises at home, do some military pushups, pullups if you have a bar, and squats. That should get you some good base muscle. Just keep going until failure

Comment: Are there any articles or something you can base your claims on?

Comment: http://www.teenbodybuilding.com/mclane15.htm has a good article for people that have trouble gaining weight. They recommend using a gym for strength training though. There's a lot of at home exercises you can do at home; pushups, pullups, squats, and situps will exercise most of the body. I highly recommend a gym though for strength and mass building

Comment: I first thought the article was good, but when reaching the bottom it was full of the usual "BUY OUR SHAKES" crap.

Comment: And it especially made me skeptical about the whole [endomorph stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatotype). _"Modern scientists, however, [...] dismiss his claims as outdated, if not outright quackery."_

Comment: I agree with you that there are some BUY OUR SHAKES stuff, but the content is good. I wouldn't recommend their stuff, but a good protein supplement (e.i. protein shakes) and really help with getting your daily protein (your weight in lbs * 1.5 = g to consume). Whey Protein is very good for ectomorphs, and you can get some relatively cheap at walmart or gnc.

Comment: mass gaining for an ectomorph is just as difficult as an endomorph trying to lose weight. These "BUY OUR SHAKES" stuff is just reccomendations to help speed along you're recovery and increase results. You get out what you put in. Simple as that

Comment: @Informaficker Your comment about somatotypes being outdated would make an excellent answer. MrBretten's answer is good as well, though I substitute "person who has always or generally been skinny" when I read "ectomorph".