# I'm very thin and I want some muscles

Tags: exercise, diet, exercise-technique

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

As the title says, I'm just thin at 5'8" and 130lbs. I'm just 19 years old. Despite eating a lot, I'm still very skinny. My problem is I'm a busy student and I don't have much time to work out. I need to do a lot of stuff the whole day in the university and most of the time I don't have a choice but to sleep at around 3AM just to finish some tasks. Yeah, that much stress while I'm still 19. I don't have the confidence to go to the gym yet so I just exercise at home or at school.

For my meals, rice really is the steady food here and it's always available (it's really in the culture to eat rice.) I can go for cereal for breakfast, though. I also like fruits.

For workouts, somebody told me to lift weights more instead of jogging. I play play basketball whenever I have time and I do some quick workouts at home (quick lifts on light dumbbells, burpees, etc.)

I'm really new to this and it's about damn time to buff up to get some hot chicks. Have you guys any suggestions on how to deal with balancing my busy schedule and my ambition on being a hunk? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think everything in [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) applies to your case. Lift heavy, eat lots (and don't miss your protein), quit the cardio, and get some sleep, or give up on gaining quality weight.

Comment: Sorry I haven't gone through that question before. Thanks guys

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)