# Widen chest area (side)

Tags: upper-body-workout, chest

I always see alot of professional sportsmen, that their chest/ribcage from the side-view is very wide.

For the normal average human, my arms can cover the whole of my side-view of my chest.

How would I increase the size/width of my chest? I want to reach something like the photo below.

[image]

Comment: a TON of pullovers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well thank you, you just made me feel like a freak :)

I think some of it is probably genetics, like how large your ribcage is. I'm not really sure, but that is probably not going to change that much. So it is very likely that regardless what you do you won't look exactly like the guy on the photo. Nevertheless, you can do the best with what you have.

Since you probably can't widen your ribcage you can do something with you chest and back muscles. For that you need a little surplus in energy (eat more then spend).
For training I would recommend chins, press and bench press for your upper body development. Throw in deadlifts and squats for symmetry. Try to lift heavier and heavier. I think starting strength is a pretty good point to start from.

Comment: To look like the guy in the photo I'd start with the funny face first, seems to be the easiest ;)

Comment: Thanks for your advise, will hopefully get started on it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Squats, deadlift, and bench press helped me in this respect. If you haven't done those heavy, I would focus on them for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. How many reps should I do? As in, high rep or low rep?

Comment: @Richard80 If you're new to squats/deadlifts/presses, I'd focus on a general strength program like I describe [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771). You don't necessarily have to eat big, but a basic barbell program would be called for. If you're familiar with barbell work I can't say I'm knowledgable enough to give further advice.