# Maintaining a healthy body for a teenager

Tags: health, weight-gain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

I am a 18 yr old guy with height of 6 ft. I have had a thin body from my childhood. My weight is around 66 kg. Although I do not do much of exercise, but have to cycle around 6-8 km everyday. I do not want to become fat, but rather just wish to have a healthy and fit looking body. I take almost everything is my diet and there is no restriction in that. I wish if you could tell me a diet plan or the exercises that I may do to achieve the desired results. Thanks!

Comment: At the moment your whole question is too vague to be reasonably answered, what does your current diet look like, what equipment do you have available (are you willing to join a gym)? What do you mean by _healthy and fit looking_?

Comment: As @Informaficker stated, the question is very broad and "maintaining a healthy body" can encompass a large number of things in the context of physical fitness. I suggest narrowing the question to something more specific (this may likely involve some more exploration on your own of what it is you seek) to get a better answer. Also please take a look at our [faq] to get a better idea of what this site is and how it works.

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing. As far as my diet is concerned, it primarily consists of cereals with vegetables of many types. I live in my college hostel, so there is very little I can do for that to change. I do not take any fast food and I require a lots of energy to perform the work throughout the day which is of around 18 hours. Now about what I meant from being healthy is whether my height and weight are normal as they should be or do I need to gain a little weight? And If I require so - I do not want it to be in terms of fat. Just fit enough. I don't have any plan of gym. Just normal ex.

Comment: The age is also a factor. I do not wish to look like a big grown adult (as it would when I gain considerable weight). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your question, please join this proposal instead:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition