# Body building diet

Tags: bodybuilding, muscle-mass

What's a good diet for bodybuilding nothing too crazy just what to eat and what not to eat and how much of a portion to gain mass and not be skinny anymore?

Comment: Hi Juan, I strong recommend that you join this site to allow us to get it up and running:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition.  Your question would be of great interest to us there.

Comment: Hi Juan.  It's very easy.  Use a calorie calculator like [this one](http://www.healthytrimcoach.com/caloric-intake-calculator/) to figure out your maintenance level.  Eat 100-500 calories over that level and make sure you get 1 gram of protein per pound of bodyweight per day.  Once you gain 5 or 10 lbs, recalculate.  You shouldn't need to change anything else. (Increasing meal frequency hasn't really been proven to do any good.) Simply put: eat a little more and get enough protein.

Comment: [This answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) talks briefly about the nutrition side of it, and in more detail about the non-dietary side of getting bigger.

Comment: This question is too broad to be reasonably answered, we have a lot of comparable questions already asked and answered on this site and I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your goals. Personally, my goals are to gain weight.

My diet matches many bodybuilder's diets pretty well. I'm not too strict though, it is easily do-able.

**Morning:**

- 6:30am - "Zone Perfect" protein bar and 1/3 cup of oatmeal (whole grain) (mixed with applesauce)
         -- This gives a good balance of protein and healthy carbs and sugars. Breakfast is a very important meal of the day! Don't pass it up. I would subsitiute *eggs* in here if you have time to make them!
- 8am - Banana
- 9am -  Peanut butter sandwich (whole wheat bread with about 1.5 servings of peanut butter)
- 11am - Turkey, Chicken, Ham, 3 leaves of Romaine lettuce (for a little bit of fat and taste - This sandwich is very high in protein)

**Afternoon:**

- 1pm - (same as 11am)
- 4pm - serving of peanut butter
- 5pm - 6-8 oz of chicken breast on whole wheat bread

**Workout time!** - (This time varies depending on my routine for the day)

**Evening:**

- (At most 30 minutes after workout) - [Post workout shake](http://www.gnc.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2296122)
- 8pm - 6-8oz of chicken breast on a mixed greens salad
- (Before bed) Peanut butter on whole wheat - This step is very important because you rebuild a lot of your muscle while you sleep!

Just maintain a high-protein diet similar to this and I believe you will be satisfied!

**Saturday:** (or the day you rest)

**Edit:** I should also *greatly* emphasize the [importance of drinking plenty of water](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/jenheath4.htm).

- Eat what you want! Not necessarily healthy.

---

I have seen a lot of personal gains using this diet. I have gained 40lbs in the past 2 years. (from 120-160) I'm 20 years old and 5' 11".

Answer (score 0):

For "not to be skinny" you just need to eat more.

- Calculate the calories you need to steadily increase your weight.
- Try to eat atleast every 3hours.
- You don't need a strict diet but don't cheat by getting your calories from something like candy and Coca cola.
- Emphasize foods with high protein content (lean meats, eggs, fish, cottage cheese, quark) or just add some whey/casein powder to your diet.

I always got bad looks from people that were trying to lose weight when I said that trying to gain weight is not much more fun than losing weight. Both require discipline and a healthy diet. Gaining weight requires you to eat more frequently and when you are not feeling hungry which in the beginning will feel bad but you'll soon get hang of it if you just stick with it.