# What are the best exercises to have bigger/stronger arms but bold/firm hips and thighs?

Tags: exercise, thigh, arms, hip

I want to fix these problems(according to my own opinion) which are having narrow/very slim arms and soft hips and thighs. I do different sports and think these problems are limiting me in some of them that I need stronger arms and surely having firmer hips and thighs can make me more beautiful and gives a better shape to my body. Which exercises do you suggest me for this reason? Please consider that I do not want to lose weight!

Comment: don't worry about weightloss advice - this site tends to have a bias towards gaining muscle mass and strength training.  :)

Comment: @DavidR :)) I got it!

Comment: Do you just want to get generally stronger and more muscular?  This may address your interests:  http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836

Comment: I want to have stronger and bigger muscles in arms and firmer muscles in hips and thighs.Gaining more weight can damage the shape of my body that I like it now. I want to only shape it and fix it for sports that I do them and like them however like all women I think to beauty too. :)

Comment: @DavidR Isn't this a fitness forum?  She is asking how to have bigger and stronger arms, so why wouldn't we give her advice on how to become bigger and stronger?

Comment: @user37324 have a look at this >  http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2011/07/21/meet-staci-your-new-powerlifting-super-hero/

Comment: @user37324 Women often have the misconception that gaining muscle means they will "bulk up" when it couldn't be further from the truth.  Not only will you look better, but you'll have less back/neck problems and generally feel better when you are stronger.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc Agree!

Comment: @user37324 Are you a female?

Comment: @Kate Yes! I am! :)

Comment: Cool! I was just making sure everyone's assumptions were correct :) I agree with what's been said so far, and Moses's answer is good. Strength training will get you what you want! Do you have access to a barbell and gym? What are your equipment restrictions, if any?

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc - no, I must have come off wrong.  I wanted to re-assure her that no one here would encourage her to lose weight, if that's not what she wanted.  My 2nd comment was a link to a general strength training Q&A.  I meant to ask if that's what she was looking for, or had very specific body-builder-ish goals

Comment: @Kate I have access to gym and all equipments related but I do not have enough knowledge to know how to use them for this reason. Surly there are coaches to guide me but they have different advices. This question is to find best advices then I can make best decisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number one workout you should absolutely be doing is the squat. It is bar-none the best functional exercise you can do, and it will work out your [entire leg](http://www.livestrong.com/article/328228-target-muscle-area-for-squats/). A second workout to consider is the deadlift which is a good supplementary exercise alongside the squat.

As for arms, you're really going to want to target the triceps, shoulder, upper back, and chest to get a well-rounded and functional strength to apply in your sports. The bench press, the overhead press, and the bentover row will all build larger arms while also building necessary strength in the chest, shoulder, and back. Push ups, chin ups, pull ups, and handstands are all good body weight exercises that target these areas if you don't wish to involve barbells.

As for not losing weight, that is up to your diet. At its simplest, it comes down to calories in (consumed) versus calories out (burned). Figure out what your daily caloric intake needs to be to maintain your weight, factor in the calories burned from your sports and weightlifting, and you have your number of calories required to maintain your weight. However, I recommend eating 200-400 calories over maintenance to fuel muscle growth.