# Does boxing interfere with gaining muscle?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, bodybuilding, boxing

I would like to gain muscle, weight and at the same time be flexible, in good condition, and do competitions in near future in boxing. For that, after the recommendations, I bought the proteins and aminos.

Does boxing 3 times in a week interfere (or slower) with gaining muscles?

Here is my workout calendar everyday after 19h except Sunday:

```
Mon:  Boxing  
Tue:  Bodybuilding  
Wed:  Boxing  
Thu:  Bodybuilding  
Fri:  Boxing  
Sat:  Bodybuilding  
Sun:  nothing
```

At the same time I want to be in a good shape of course and loose fat.

Comment: Have you tried to search this site? See http://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=weight+gain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly everything except eating, resting, and lifting heavy weights slows down muscle growth. So, yes, boxing will somewhat interfere with your bodybuilding. [This answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) may help.

However, it doesn't sound like your goal is "get bigger", it's "get fitter in every way", so your current amount of boxing is fine. Boxing will improve your conditioning, as well as your ability to box and to compete. However, you might get more results out of powerlifting or Olympic lifting rather than bodybuilding, since those would develop strength and power more than muscle size.

Comment: 1st question: Resting - it means i should sleep more ? i am an IT and i am seating the whole day in front of computer, so iam relaxed, does it help to rest muscles after workout?

2nd question: Of course i would like to gain in mass and also in power but You said doing powerlifting will develop strength and power, it means only power itself, or also in mass ( getting bigger). thank you for info

Comment: @aspirinemaga You'll certainly need to sleep and eat a lot to recover properly from six days a week of training. Sitting at a computer does not help; it just makes you less flexible. Powerlifting will build both size and strength and some power. Olympic lifting will build power and strength and some size.