# I want to gain weight. 15 KGs in 5 months

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, weight-gain, weights, bodyweight-exercises

I am 28 Years old Male. My height is 5.6 feet, and weight is 45 KG. My BMI is 17, and I am underweight.

I look very skinny, and I get insulted by many people when I am in public gatherings like Birthdays, marriages etc. I look like a teenager.

After 4 months I am going to get married, and for that I want to look like a MAN and not like a kid.

Please suggest weight gaining exercises, foods, and supplements (if required).
I am a non vegetarian and non alcoholic. I want to look like a healthy person. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771). Basically: squat heavy barbells, eat plenty of good food, and rest a lot.