# How many sets should I make for muscle growth?

Tags: exercise, muscle, biceps, chest

I have a very skinny body. So I try to train a lot to change that.
I want to make my biceps and chest bigger first, so I do push-ups and pull-ups.

Every other day im doing 12 sets of push ups, every other day i do 12 sets of pullups. I take 2 min rest between the sets.

The number of reps varies between the sets. They may look like `35-30-30-27-26-25-24-23-22-21-20-19` for the push ups and `17-14-13-12-11-10-10-9-9-9-8-8` forthe pull ups.

**Im afraid that the volume of my training and its frequency will stunt muscle growth and wont let me reach my goal.**

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "exact" muscle growth?

Comment: I edited the question to be more readable as I understand it, feel free to revert the changes if i misunderstood. As for the question itself, if you want to get bigger, dont ask us if what youre doing is wrong - try searching for what is the best way to gain muscle, there has been plenty of that here. Like this one: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle Once youve read these and still got questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: There isn't even a question here…

Comment: I'm not sure that doing 300 total reps of anything is going to cause much growth; especially the workouts you have selected.

Comment: this is what i really mean, `Im afraid that the volume of my training and its frequency will stunt muscle growth and wont let me reach my goal.`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are doing a large amount of repetitions on a limited number of exercises. It sounds like you are only doing two exercises.

Bodies are designed to adapt, if you just do the same two exercises over and over again you are only focusing on a limited number of muscles and they will easily adapt to this limited set of exercises and you will only get a very limited benefit.

The other thing is, once your body adapts it is going to plateau because you are not increase the weight or resistance. I am guessing once you could do a 100 standard push-ups your body adapted and you saw no further benefit.

I'm happy for other people's input, but my suggestion is you shouldn't be doing more than 2 or 3 reps of the same exercise, say (2 or 3) x 10. You can then use your remaining strength and energy doing a different exercise. There are different types of push-ups you can do, so maybe you could do 3 sets of 10 with 3 different types of push-up then move onto another exercise.

You can also increase weight while doing push-ups and pull-ups by using a weighted backpack.

I also suggest you look at doing some sort of weights training. If you don't want a trainer or go to a gym, go online you can search for a wide variety of exercises for specific muscle groups and mix it up.

Comment: have a doubt....i have already doing nearly 300 push ups,but u suggest me to do do (3x10)x3=90 push ups.in my current condition i think it will not burn my muscles,then how the muscle growth take place.`actually i'm a beginner,so it may rise foolish questions from my side...i'm sorry`

Comment: Because you are doing too many pushups, so you are already getting no benefit (no muscle growth). You should do 10 reps of 3 different types of push-up and use your remaining energy to do other exercise. Even if you are exercising the same muscle group, your body will respond better to a variety of exercise. If you do 600 of the same type of push-up you are also likely going to see no difference to your muscles.

Answer (score 1):

Doing push-ups and pull-ups is great. However, since you're doing them so frequently and with so much repetitions, your muscles are getting used to it.

You have to shock your muscles to get them to grow. Now, what does that mean? Actually it's simple: switch up your rotation! Try 1 push-up over 12 seconds: push up slowly, then hold, then go down slowly again. You should start to notice that reps become more difficult and your muscles should begin to burn a lot earlier. Same goes for pull-ups.

If you're trying to grow muscles, you should switch up your routine every 3-4 weeks in my opinion. For my body, my muscles are adapted to my routine after about 3 weeks so then I switch from heavy weights to lower weights but more repetitions, after that I increase the weight a bit (but not maxing out) and slow down my repetitions.

Comment: 1)what should be my frequency?  2)How to know a muscle become adapted?

Comment: Well, if you would take a longer time to do 1 repetition, you can do way less because it takes more effort. And how to know a muscle becomes adapted.. the exercise becomes easier and easier (also lighter) and your muscles aren't sore the next day.

Comment: 1)`did you feel,i am overuse my muscle by doing 12 sets 3 time a week for the same part?` 2)`I am not feeling the adaptation.because i feel so harder everyday` 3)`what is the advantage of rest day?currently i have no rest day`

Comment: I dont understand question 1 and 2 :p could you re-format those? and for question 3: rest days are really important because those are the days that your muscles are supposed to do nothing so they can rebuild. If you do not give them rest, you will keep tearing them (building muscles is nothing else than tearing your muscles just a little bit, the bigger your muscle get the more "scar" tissue there is on your muscle) and they will have no time to rebuild themselves.

Comment: `1)`By doing 300 push ups,will be there any damages for muscles? `2)`My workout never felt easy to me. So I cannot feel my muscles adapted.

Answer (score 0):

by 300 push ups u can gain little muscle and better endurance(strength).endurance exersices are so tiersome.tobe changed quicly you have to exercise with every part of your muscle. if you are interested try this schedule.
Mon-p/up=120(4varieties)
           Pull up=90(wide,narrow&back)
Tue-rest
Wed-abdomens 
           Waist,qudriceps (leg)
Thu-biceps&triceps(with dumbells)
Fri- rest
sat-repeat Mon exercice(more differnt varieties)Sun-rest
The other thing is you have to eat 4-6 small meals per day not let your body fell hungry''eat more than you think.''drink 2-4liters of water.
You 'll do this ex for 2 weeks and change only the varieties on the next 2 weeks.there are 148 varieties of push ups.you can get from youtube.
Wish u a good posture thanks.
Fogot something.............................. focus on ur abdomens.

Comment: what is the maximum relaxation time between two sets?