# how to gain weight without joining gym

Tags: nutrition, muscle, workout, weight-gain, supplements

I Am Rachit Chopra a clg students.

Basically regulatory I go to clg and after in evening time I go to my dad's office to experience some good thing, Because this is my final year of clg. So, after I have to join my dad business so for sake of it I have condenser on clg n dad business. As you know both are important for me after in got very much tried.

So some time I try to wake up early in morning to go to gym but after doing so much of work and clg, it's was difficult for me to wake up for gym also. Sorry for a long story.

Basically I just want to ask you how can I put on my weight without joining gym. I am 20 yrs old and my weight is 55kg only and my height is 5.7 and as you know in today's life it's so important to get a good body and after its all about personality.

So come you will give me some good suggestions that can be help me. You can also contact me on my g-mail id-RACHITCHOPRA02@MAIL.COM
thanks

Comment: Hi Rachit! This question has been asked before, please take a look [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle). You may want to ask a separate question about what equipment to use for a home gym, I don't know if it's on here but that would be a great question.

Comment: It is a duplicate. And while I realize that English is not your first language, please avoid shortening words (imp for important, u for you), etc. It makes it much harder to read and guess at what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Title of this issue is a little different than the I'm underweight question in that this person is trying to do it without a gym.  Not sure what "clg" is though.  Please expand.  Bottom line is that the principles in the linked question seriously do apply.  The only difference is finding out what you have available to you for training outside of a gym.

Comment: Also, you don't want to put your email in a question.  The spirit of the site is to answer questions here.  If you ask a question, and get an answer but it isn't here it won't help anyone else.