# How can I gain muscle in two months without using weights?

Tags: muscle-mass

What can a 15 year old boy who weighs 145 pounds and is 6' tall do to gain a lot of muscle and size without using weights?

I'm looking for results in two months and I work out for half an hour a day.

Answer (score 4):

### Buy Weights or Join a Gym

How can you gain a lot of muscle in two months? [Get access to a barbell and squat rack, squat and press heavy three times a week, eat a lot of food, and sleep a lot](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836). Your restrictions (half-hour workouts, no weights) make it unlikely that you'll get much bigger and muscled in less than a year.

Start saving your money to buy some dumbbells or a barbell, because come on, they work better. Used equipment is cheap if cost is an issue.

### Adding muscle without barbells

If you absolutely refuse to lift a barbell (or even a dumbbell or kettlebell), then you could see *some* results from three to six months of upper-body work. That means a whole lot of chin-ups, pull-ups, dips, and push-ups (including divebomber or handstand variations). In order to avoid totally neglecting your lower body, do some squats, pistol squats, and back extensions as well.

I saw a modest improvement in my shoulders, upper arms, and upper back from four months of doing 3 maximal sets each of pull-ups and dips. I only added five or ten pounds of muscle, however. Three workouts a week with a minimum of 50 pull-ups and dips would be a fine start to a muscular upper body.

### Eat

To get bigger, you must give your body the raw materials with which to make more of you. Eat a lot of vegetables and pastured meat, milk, and eggs. Focus on food quality--avoid soda, junk and deep-fried food, get grass-fed beef and dairy--but don't forget to simply eat a lot.

Comment: While I agree on your answer, I think the boy needs some realistic expectations on how much muscle to expect on half hour a day with body weight only exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed a guy named Matt Furey and his workouts will get you some real results without using any weights.

Here is a link to his website http://www.mattfurey.com/index.htm

You can also read the following to get more insight http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/mahler19.htm

BTW - I don't want overstep my boundaries but to my knowledge a boy at 15 if he is that tall and its not common in the family he should probably be taken to the doctor to verify that he is not suffering from gigantism.

> Routine #1: Killer 200 Pushup Workout: 3 minute back bridge 100 Hindu Squats 50 Hindu Pushups German 50: 10 Elbows in, 10 hand over hand, 10 Superman, 10 hands wide, 10 hands backwards performed in a row, without stopping. 25 Hindu Pushups with feet 10" apart 25 Hindu Pushups with feet together 25 Hindu Pushups with hands and feet together 25 fingertip Hindu Pushups 3 minute back bridge, 3 minute front bridge Routine #2: 3 Minute Back Bridge 100 Hindu Squats 10 Grasshoppers 35 Bootstrappers 10 Kneeling Back Bends 20 Hindu Jumper Squats 10 Mountain Climbers

This is officially a beginners routine, but for most this will be too much, so do the sets as listed but with less reps.

Comment: Hey, how about adding a quick summary here of what Matt Furey's workout approach is? Protects from link breakage, and gives people a reason to click to learn more...

Comment: The above comment, and, lol! Don't worry, my dad is 5.11" at 42 years old, so we good bro.

Comment: Routine #1: Killer 200 Pushup Workout:
3 minute back bridge
100 Hindu Squats
50 Hindu Pushups
German 50: 10 Elbows in, 10 hand over hand, 10 Superman, 10 hands wide, 10 hands backwards performed in a row, without stopping.
25 Hindu Pushups with feet 10" apart
25 Hindu Pushups with feet together
25 Hindu Pushups with hands and feet together
25 fingertip Hindu Pushups
3 minute back bridge, 3 minute front bridge

Routine #2: 
3 Minute Back Bridge
100 Hindu Squats
10  Grasshoppers
35 Bootstrappers
10 Kneeling Back Bends
20 Hindu Jumper Squats
10 Mountain Climbers

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that this officially a beginners routine, but for most this will be too much, so do the sets as listed but with less reps.