# Body building and gaining weight

Tags: diet, workout-routines, nutrition, bodybuilding, protein

I am 20 age and my weight is 52 kg I am so thin like skeletal I want to gain weight and how I can make my body please help me

Comment: Yea, I empathize. Check out [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771), then go forth and eat, verily, and uplift the bar-belles.