# How can i quickly gain Weight ? i am too skinny

Tags: diet, weight-gain

I want to gain weight quickly.  What can i do?  Please suggest for me **a diet that is not too expensive**.

Comment: What's the quality of weight gain, and amount of weight gain we are talking about?  How patient are you?  Do you want muscle with the weight?  Check the other Related topics on the right to see if your particulars have been addressed.  If not, add some info.  For example, what's your definition of "not too expensive diet"?

Comment: What type of workout routine (if any) do you have?

Comment: [This](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) might help, if you're looking to gain muscle or just plain get bigger.