# How to become Fat

Tags: body-fat, fat

I am 23 years old and my height is 6 feet, my weight is 59 and I am looking very thin. What diet and exercise programme should I follow to become little fatty. I even going to the gym for 2 months but not use till now. Can anyone suggest me a better way?

BTW I don't eat Non Veg Food (But I will eat eggs).

Comment: See [this answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/14465/1771).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I gain lean muscle mass as a vegetarian or vegan?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14455/how-do-i-gain-lean-muscle-mass-as-a-vegetarian-or-vegan)

Comment: I'm hesitant to vote to close as a duplicate until the duplicate has at least one more answer. Mine is pretty minimal as it is. Plus, I'm not even veg*n!

Comment: Getting fat is easy.  If the goal is just to get fat, do nothing and eat a lot more than you do now.  In fact eat bad things for you.  Problem is this wrecks your hormonal balance.  If you want to stay healthy, look at the number of similar questions about adding muscle while minimizing extra fat.

Comment: You didn't answer you commented.

Comment: @Hituptony, that's because it's not a real answer.

Comment: @Kate don't worry about it, it wasn't you..?

Answer (score 2):

Your aim should not be to become fat, rather you should aim to gain healthy weight/build up muscle/gain some lean mass.

To do this your body needs to be in a calorie surplus.  I.e. you eat more calories than your body actually needs.  These calories should be from a good source, i.e. oats, eggs, fish (If you are a pesco pollo vegetarian) etc. If you are eating bad calories such as crisps, fries, anything starchy etc you will gain weight, however you won't look physically fit.

If you're a hard gainer, you may want to use a weight gainer or you can try using creatine, or other products such as Cyclone (From maximuscle). You will probably need to do a creatine loading phase and then take around 5mg of creatine to maintain it in your system and consume a lot of water (Around 3 litres a day).  Using these products can help as a dietary supplement and with the correct workout will help you gain some lean muscle.

Comment: creatine loading is no longer considered "needed", you can take a standard dose every day results will just come a bit slower. However, the question is how to become fat, not how to build muscle...

Comment: http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/creatine-q-and-a-top-17-questions-answered.html

Comment: @Hituptony - having taking it myself I have always been advised to do a loading phase then a 5mg maintenance phase.  This worked for me so I am only going off my personal experience here.  While the question is how to become fat, I don't think this is what the OP actually means, I've never heard of anyone wanting to become fat and look saggy, rather they mean how do they add weight.  This stack exchange is about physical fitness, we should not point the OP in the direction of getting into bad eating habits and gaining bad weight which will affect his physical health.

Comment: Personal experience is a nice approach, and I take that as well sometimes, but if information cannot be backed up, or is perhaps specific to YOUR exp., will OP see the results they desire. I see what you're saying about building lean mass, and not guiding the OP into the direction of bad eating habits, however, the title of the question is really, "How to become fat", what you THINK the OP is trying to ask should be verified by the OP before a real answer is given. I'll remove neg if you can confirm that you got "fat" from using the methods in your answer.

Comment: @Hituptony - As an experienced poster on the stack exchange sites, I have found that the majority of the time I have somehow had to decipher what the OP actually means in order to give an answer I believe is correct. I find it a taj harsh you have down voted my answer when the other answers guide the OP to gain lean muscle weight and adopt a healthy eating regime, which is the same as what I have posted.

Comment: This is not me picking on you. The OP says weight is 59lbs and is a vegetarian. You mention to eat fish as part of his vegetarian diet. Your advice is general, and could apply to ANYONE who wants to gain lean muscle mass. This is a very specific scenario that may deserve input from someone who can assist in a dietary regime, as by the height to weight ratio, OP could have eating disorder. Easing into a diet that will compliment healthy weight gain should also be mentioned, as if calorie restriction is too great, the body is starved of nutrients.

Comment: OP is skinnier than a stick. and for your direct translation: He has tagged his post with body-fat, and fat. NOT muscle-building, lean mass..etc. So your perception of his intent may be a bit off sir.

Comment: My bad for the confusion of including fish in, I know some pesco pollo vegetarians who eat fish, however that's straying away from the point and I will remove it from my answer. I have recommended certain elements of a diet that can aid in healthy weight gain which is my entire point and believe it will help the OP. We were earlier in debate over the topic of how the OP should gain fat which I personally believe this stack exchange site is not about. I'm unsure where your calorie restriction comment has came from as that is completely off topic.

Comment: is it? Hm. I don't think all 59lbs can be chalked up to "hard-gaining", he would at least stay at a relatively normal weight for someone 6'... Of all answers, you gave solid advice and didn't stray too much. Just a few points I wanted to make. I agree this is not a fitness exchange question and will second your vote to close. Also, I removed my neg, and gave it to tinyByte ;). I hope you have not taken offense. I see your points, I hope you see mine. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you actually want to be "fat" or look muscular and fit. You are actually looking towards having a more balanced and attractive physique.

Getting muscular or getting thin, both requires effort and time and does not happen in a couple of months. You need to have patience and track your progress on a weekly basis. Diet and workout both play a role here. Give yourself at least 4 months to see a visible change.

Do not adopt unhealthy eating habits or laziness to get fat. This will do you a lot of harm and invite diseases and weakness.

Eat more, but eat healthy foods, full of nutrition. Like adding more protein, more fibre and fruits/veggies. Add carbs too but be balanced with sugars and fats. Add jaggery/brown sugar and olive oil to your diet. Add almonds, raisins and walnuts. Just because you want to increase your body mass, do not load yourself with sugary and fatty stuff.

Include weight training, free body exercises to your routine. The ratio of weight training to cardio should be more in terms of time devoted, like 40 minutes of weights followed by 15 mins of cardio. Do weight training after warming up and cardio as a last exercise before cool down. Do squats and pushups as they increase total body strength. If you include whey protein in your diet it will be better, but its not mandatory if you are getting enough protein elsewhere. You should have a before and after workout diet. Before workout, have fibrous carbs and after workout have protein and fast absorbing carbs.

Hope it helps. This is from personal experience and watching other people do the same.

Answer (score 0):

there is a phase were you go to gym and you should keep this in mind that every good thing happens over time, you first need to make your body strong so it can handle more pressure and more weight,

the more pressure you put on your muscles, the more you need to eat protein and more rest ofcourse,

resting is very important part of healing and muscle making!

basically you need to go to gym on regular basis and keep a good proteinful diet, and don't forget to consult with a good doctor and gym trainer.

Comment: pressure put on muscles? Do you mean resistance? pressure makes me think about squeezing my bicep

Comment: I mean doing workouts with heavy weights, that will make you buff