# Need to gain weight as soon as it possible

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

I am girl, I am only 17 years old, soon I am going to be 18. I am only 35 kg and my height is 154 cm. I really want to gain some weight,
My body fitness is not good. I am not having proper body shape. Its becoming really hard to increase my weight. I am 35 kg from last 2 years!! I also want to increase my height.
My daily food habit-
For morning, 1/2 breads with vegetable or with eggs
For lunch, 1 plate rice with vegetable or fish or meat (depends on what is cooked )
For dinner, half plate rice with vegetable or meat or fish (depends on what is cooked )
I normally have 6 mugs of water

Can you please suggest me a proper diet plan, and what types of food will help me to increase my weight? 
PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: [This answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) should be right up your alley.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, height is not something you'll have much control over. It basically boils down to genetics. Which brings me to my next point that you are very short so putting on a lot of a weight isn't going to be easy. However, 35kg is **very** light and at your height, your ideal body weight should be around **50 kg (range 43 to 58 kg)**.

As Dave has pointed out, there are several other well answered questions on how to gain size/weight such as [an answer from Dave Liepmann himself.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836) If you would like to attempt to source more information from the internet, the process is typically referred to in the body-building community as 'bulking' so a simple google search of this will return a more detailed plethora of information.