# High metabolism problems

Tags: weightlifting, weight-gain, metabolism

I fluctuate in my weight very regularly. I can gain 5 lbs in 1-2 days, no problem. But if I don't workout and or eat the same amount as I did the day before, the 5 lbs magically disappears.

It's frustrating trying to gain mass when I have no ability to hold my weight for more than a day.

Is there any tips/tricks to possibly slow down a metabolism?

Comment: Erik's answer is correct. A 5 lb gain in 1-2 days is all food/water, and not permanent. (And vice versa). True fat or muscle gain of 5 lbs will take much longer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

Answer (score 2):

The weight you're gaining and losing is water weight. Water binds to glucose and salt, amongst other things in your diet. It's simply not possible to remove 5lbs of fat, muscle, or bone from someone (without a knife) in 1-2 days.

If you want to gain muscle and be fit, you should [look into an effective strength training program like Starting Strength and ensure you're eating enough protein](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836) ([link](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836)).

Comment: on a zero carbs with  refills my top  record was 7 kg in 3 days. it can be nothing except the water weight.