# incresing weight , breast and height growth

Tags: strength

I am a 19 years old girl. My weight is 37 kg only. My height is 5"3. I am a very slim and skinny girl. My problem is, my breasts are very small or you can say I  have no breasts. I want to gain weight and increase my breasts size by joining a gym . And if possible I also wish to increase my height to 5"6.So I request you to please suggest me what should I do.

Comment: You can not increase height, neither breast size by training. On gaining weight, see: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle

Comment: Ditch the body image you're looking for. There is nothing wrong and everything right with a 5'3" fit and healthy girl.

Answer (score -1):

You can't increase breast size the way you want it to by going to the gym. Neither can you change your height, basketball is an option for this although you won't increase your height by a lot.

You can have a nice body by going to the gym though. :)