# Is this diet right for bulking up?

Tags: bodybuilding

I lift 14kg for biceps.(i usually put more emphasis on biceps and less on triceps and abs.)
Following is my daily schedule:
Morning:
At 7:40am
3 egg white,
1 cup of tea(it also contains milk) with chocolate biscuits containing 24g trans fat.(Maybe its trans fat,chocolate biscuits are my weakness:( )
I go to my college and come back at 12:00am.
At 1:00pm
100g meat
1 cup of tea(it also contains milk) with chocolate biscuits.
At 3:00pm
Banana shake 200ml or more.
At 9:00pm
1 pakistani roti with salan.
11:00pm
150ml milk

One more question please,how many sets for how many exercise for hypertrophy.

Comment: If you're looking to build big arms, you should emphasize triceps over biceps.  Don't exclude either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate but the votes to close based on it being off-topic due to being a nutrition question are misguided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bulking up, you should eat more and better.

1. You seem to be low on protein. 3 egg whites make almost no difference (they give you ~10g of protein), 100g of meat is very low as it gives you ~30g of proteins. Supposing you get another 10g of protein at dinner, you get ~50g per day. You should aim for 1.5g per kg of body weight per day at the very least. Up your carbs too, so you don't metabolize your proteins into energy.
2. Reduce your saturated fats for your future health. They are the bad ones, playing a role in coronary diseases. Trans fats have the same effects, so count them as saturated fats. If you eat 24g trans fat worth of biscuits twice a day, plus milk, you will actually eat more saturated fat than proteins. You shouldn't eat more than 7% of your calories as saturated fats, and no more than 30% of your daily calories as overall fat.
3. Take care of the other two pillars: sleep and exercise. Sleep as much as you can, workout every day. You actually didn't include working out in your daily schedule. Of course, there are other obvious things : no alcohol (reduces natural testosterone), no cigarette, eliminate the sources of stress, don't overdo cardio, control the amount of sodium you eat (which often comes together with protein) to, at most, 2300mg per day (less is better).