# How to gain weight with a fast metabolism and constraints on nutrition?

Tags: workout, nutrition, protein, protein-shakes, intermittent-fasting

I have been trying to get big. I can't eat too much because Im not allowed to (family problems). I'm trying to find a way to gain weight with even thhough I work out. Ive heard of intermittent fasting and protein pouders, but I'm not sure what to do. My fast metabolism is a big issue for me. I would like to know your opinions on how I should be treating myself in order to get big.
thank you

Comment: Please see also http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle but if you can't eat a lot of food, that's a basic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intermittent fasting or protein powders will not help you gain weight. Eating above your caloric maintenance will. So if you cannot eat much the answer is not more protein as protein is not as rich in calories as fat and carbohydrates. Obviously, intermittent fasting will not increase your caloric intake either.

If you cannot eat more then the only solution to gain weight is to limit activities that burn a lot of calories. That is not so as easy as eating more calories. Your activities during the day are limited and you cannot stop walking in order to gain weight.

I would advise you to find a way to put a little more food in your diet. You can try eating peanut butter,honey or other similar products that are rich in calories. Try incorporating foods in your diet that do not fill your stomach easily but are rich in calories.

I have noticed that people who say the have a fast metabolism usually do not eat as much as they think they do. Start tracking your weight and if it is possible for you track your calories as well. I know several people who started counting their calories and were surprised when they found they didn't eat as many calories as they thought.

You should count your calories or estimate your food intake and if you see that you are not gaining weight then add a little more food. If you do this for some time then you will eventually surpass your caloric maintenance and gain weight.

Just keep in mind there are two factors that influence weight. Your activities and caloric intake. There is no way for you to gain weight if you are eating less calories than you need.

Answer (score 1):

### Is my metabolism super fast?

[Actually, it's probably not.](http://www.bodyrecomposition.com/fat-loss/you-are-not-different.html) Excluding rare and serious metabolic conditions, which should be diagnosed by a doctor, people's metabolisms [tend to be within 200-300 calories of each other](http://examine.com/faq/does-metabolism-vary-between-two-people.html).

[A review article of 67 scientific studies](http://www.goranlab.com/pdf/78.pdf) found that **"when adjusted for differences in fat-free mass, resting energy expenditure values in obese and nonobese individuals tend to be comparable"** and that there is "no association of baseline resting energy expenditure with weight change among 775 men during a 10-year period". The review draws the conclusion that "Regarding metabolic factors, available data indicate that although there are variations in resting energy expenditure and in the thermic effect of food, there is little evidence that these variations contribute significantly to the observed trends in weight gain."

### You aren't eating enough.

## Eat more.

You need to have a frank discussion with your family about nutrition. Tell them you need larger portions of lean meat and veg to help you **recover** from your exercise (assuming you are exercising because you enjoy it).

Intermittent fasting is a diet plan for reducing weight. A cheaper option is whole milk. A gallon of milk a day will definitely lead to weight gain (muscle gain if paired with exercise).

Protein Powder may help but they are SUPPLIMENTS, you should know what your macronutrient breakdown is and where your nutritional gaps are before using them.