# Creatine at its Finest

Tags: workout, protein, energy, creatine, caffeine

Hello Im new to this website and Im sure that everyone here frequently gets asked about Creatine. Currently I have been taking C4 Cellucor along with Creacore Creatine by MuscleTech. I weigh 171 and I am trying to bulk up for the next season of Football. I am 5'10' and I am 15. I am trying to become a defensive lineman but I am dumbfounded of what to really use. I work out twice a day and I have been working out for over a year now. Anyone have any suggestions if I should take protein powder instead? or what else to use?

Comment: Please see @Dave Liepmann's [excellent answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836).  Taking creatine monohydrate is a good idea for pretty much everyone.  You probably need to lift heavy three times per week (not twice per day) and _eat more than you want to eat_.  Note that if you do this properly then you should not have visible "abs"; decide whether strength and athletic success are more important than appearance.  You can cut weight to reveal your abs later, after you get strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to bulk up, then make sure you're eating a surplus amount of calories every day and that you're working out.  Twice a day is not necessary, and might even lead to more harm than good.

Protein powder is another supplement which might be beneficial if your diet is lacking protein.  I imagine if you're eating in a surplus that you likely wouldn't need to take any additional protein supplements.

Keep lifting heavy weights to promote muscle growth and eating enough so that your body has the materials needed to actually build the muscle.
You'll gain muscle mass in time.