# I am 15 years old and I'm thin. I want to gain weight and muscles

Tags: exercise, muscle, workout, bodybuilding, bodyweight

I am 15 years old. I study in class 11. Please don't go to my age. I still want to gain some weight. Well, I haven't weighed myself, really. I am thin. I have no muscles. In my school life I was teased a lot. Now in college I want weight. I'm underweight. How am I going to get some weight?

Edited: my diet is just a glass of milk in the morning, then rice and vegetables, then college time starts from 11am to 5pm, and I come home and east last food (rice and others). I know this is less but I don't have time for eating. I go to college on my bicycle, it's a bit far so I lose calories. Shit.

And I have two 3kg dumbbells at my home. Will that work?

Comment: Please see @Dave Liepmann's [excellent answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle/6836#6836).

Answer (score 1):

All I can say is, you need to eat enough to gain weight. Eat something with that milk for breakfast(like a bowl of cereals, or some oats). You spent 6 hours at school, that's a pretty big time, and as you bike to school,so you are losing calories and also losing all through out those 6 hours no matter what you do. Can't you carry a small snack box with you, with something healthy in it to eat during breaks. Or a bottle with some home made shake in it? Also, try sticking to a diet that gives you complete nutrition. As you are growing, you need to eat well and eat more and eat proper, in regular intervals.

Regarding workout, do free hand workouts at home if you don't have time. Pushups, free hand squats, lunges, stretching etc. Whether those 3kg dumbbells will help or not, it depends on what you do with them. Check out some you tube videos, if you want to know what you could do with them and how to use them to workout your overall body. If your goal is to put on some weight, and you are disciplined, sticking to the above would do.