# I'm a girl of 21 years old. I'm so weak.I want to increase my body fat

Tags: body-fat

I'm a girl of 21 years old I'm so weak and look like a child. All people too much irritated me and too much hatred me to say that you are so weak. now i'm feeling so badly. These kind of people braked my heart completely.I have fade up of my life.My parents want to marry my as soon as possible.. I just want that i increase my weight and body structure please help that works soon.And please don't suggest me any exercise because i can't do any kind of exercise.

Comment: Don't listen to those people. You are a woman and you are powerful. In terms of getting fit, gaining strength, and increasing your body fat I would say start by lifting weights. Heavy weights. Show those people!

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle