# How Can I remove my muscle weakness? Please advise

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery

I’m new to this site and was wondering if someone could advise

After exercise (running) I’ve been left with a lot of weakness in my calf muscles (making it difficult to walk) and arm muscles ( so weak, everything I pick up is heavy) I’m not sure if this is due to low carbohydrates or protein and was wondering if anyone had any tips to regain strength?

Also how long on average does it take to regain strength in muscles?
Are there any supplements that could help?

Thank you for your time, I appreciate any advise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

Comment: Try with creatine. Maybe that is not the best option at start, but it can be that you are not eating enough red meat... During first year or so of intensive training I had same fillings.

Comment: When you say after exercise, do you mean the muscles feel weak the next morning, and maybe the day after that as well? What exercises did you do? Do the muscles also feel tight and achy? To me, this sounds like DOMS.

Comment: Yeah after exercise meaning running, they were just really weak the day after and since then I’ve been struggling to gain the strength back in the muscles, there is no tightness or achy just weakness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This honestly just sounds like a case of DOMS. What is that? “Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness”, it’s a side effect training muscles more than normal. DOMS is a sign that your muscles are breaking down, and if you provide your body with sufficient protein, then they will rebuild themselves to be stronger and bigger. DOMS is not necessary for muscle growth, but it can be a friendly reminder.

How do you get rid of DOMS? When your muscles have been sufficiently rebuilt, the soreness will pass. DOMS is not a sign to stop working out however, it’s perfectly normal. Pain on the other hand is a sign to stop working out. If you suddenly feel a sharp pain while working out (or during physical activity), it is possible that you could have strained a muscle, and a strained muscle needs rest. It may be hard to distinguish between the two as a beginner, but try to gauge whether the muscles feel exhausted and “weak”, or compromised and painful.

Nutrition and rest are key to recovery though. As far as rest goes, try to limit your workouts to an hour or less per day, 5 days per week. As far as nutrition goes, try to consume 1.5-2.0 times your kg body weight in grams of protein, this will ensure that your body has plenty to work with. Your balance of fats and carbs isn’t too important as long as you are eating from healthy sources and eating a reasonable number of calories for your goals (see a TDEE Calculator). Supplements exist to supplement your diet in areas that you might be missing out on. The most useful supplements are Protein Powders, Omega 3s, Multivitamins, and Creatine. Double check your diet though and do your own research to determine how much of each you will want/need (no supplement is 100% necessary, but they are certainly beneficial).

Finally, ensure that you are following a competent fitness plan. Following a well thought out plan created by someone who knows what they are doing will ensure that your muscles have time to recover and grow between workouts. Not only that, but it will also ensure that you are making the most out of the time you spend working out. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you JustSnilloc for your tips, I appreciate it, I’d say I’m more just worried about the weakness, if that goes I can cope with the rest, thank you so much for your time