# Reaching 200 kilograms/440 pounds bodyweight at less than 35% bodyfat

Tags: weight-gain

I would like to know the healthiest way to reach a mass of 200 kilograms (440 lbs) without killing myself. I would need to gain 127 kilograms, as I am currently sitting at 73 kilograms at 14% body fat.

My physique goal looks like this...
[image]

Comment: The person in that photo did not get that way by being healthy.

Comment: This question is in a sense "what's the healthiest way to get unhealthy?" Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: As the others have stated, this question is self-contradictory. Please edit the question to resolve such inconsistencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

Comment: Eat, lift, eat, sleep, repeat with a little more weight next time. I don't think anyone gets that big (without simply being fat) without [incredible feats of food](https://startingstrength.com/article/eating_through_the_sticking_points), lifting a hell of a lot, and maybe a little exogenous hormone supplementation.

Comment: It's best to have a medical professional monitor your progress, as reaching that level you posted in your picture is not "healthy". Most strength competitors look like this because they lift a lot of weight but they are not concerned with how they look, as they are not getting judged based on their physique but on true numbers, so a lot of them don't "diet" but just eat a lot of food. I watched a documentary where they said it is impossible to lift a lot of weight without weighing a lot yourself because cutting the fat down and using a calorie deficit greatly diminishes your strength.

Comment: I have voted to keep this question open, primarily because it has implications outside of the question of rapid muscle gain—namely health and limitations of (natural) muscle growth.

Answer (score 2):

First, it should be stated clearly that, for men, body fat of greater than 25% constitutes one [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_obesity) of obesity. Your goal of 35% would not be considered ‘healthy’ by any scientific or medical organisation.

Nevertheless, if we temporarily disregard body fat and consider only lean muscle mass, your goals are still well beyond what evidence tells us is achievable—at least without extreme drug and supplement abuse. A study by Casey Butt, PhD. documented the anthropomorphic measurements, fat, and lean mass of elite ‘natural’ bodybuilders, beginning in the late 1930s, and his findings culminated in a formula that would estimate our absolute (natural) potential for lean muscle gain. And whilst it has been noted that ‘natural’ status of many of his subjects is questionable, it does provide us with some evidentiary foundation for what is practically possible. His formula is as follows:

[image]

Whereby *H* is your height in inches, *A* is your ankle circumference at the smallest point, *W* is your wrist circumference at the [styloid process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulnar_styloid_process), and *bf* is your body fat percentage.

That research revealed maximum Fat-Free Mass Indices of around 25 kilogram metres (kg.m). For reference, [the median (Caucasian) height-adjusted Fat-Free Mass Index (AdjFFMI) of untrained men is 18.9 kg.m](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12080449/), and [male college-level athletes have been found to have an average AdjFFMI of 22.8 kg.m](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30985525/), suggesting that those findings are, at least, within the bounds of reason. So if we accept Butt's conclusions and formula, the average man would be limited to approximately 18-23 kilograms (40-50 lbs) of muscle gain after reaching adulthood. The rest would necessarily be fat.

***So whilst you certainly could reach your goal mass, since [fat is the only component of our bodies for which there is no limit](https://medium.com/@drjasonfung/understanding-obesity-f233fbb38dc1), you could not achieve that goal muscularly or healthily.***

I hope that helps.

Comment: You mean that professional strongmen are all in PEDs because they physically can't build all the muscle naturally? I'm shocked. SHOCKED... well not that shocked.

Comment: @DeeV: Not necessarily, of course. Competitive (professional) strongmen are genetic freaks in terms of height, fibre type, and natural hormone levels. Yes, as with *all* power sports, there is undoubtedly a huge prevalence of use of performance-enhancing drugs, but the extreme size and strength of strongmen is as much a function of outlying genetics as it is drug abuse.