# Exercises to hide bulging lower hip bone

Tags: strength-training, training

Now, I have seen a lot of posts about individuals with wide hips, but I feel that my body structure is quite uniquely problematic.

I have relatively broad shoulders, a very thin waist, and a normal upper hip. This seems fine, but then you get to my lower hip and it all goes downhill.

My thigh bone bulges out of my hip, with the trochanter of my femur bulging out of my body. It isn't some sort of disease or anything, it is just the bone stabbing out of my body.

This bulge makes my body structure look weird. It's sort of hourglassy, which is bad, but the base of the hourglass is low, which makes my upper body look slightly better.

However, it's still immensely problematic that this damn bulge is here. It looks jarring as it comes out of my relatively-normal hips, and even more jarring as my thighs are a lot thinner than the bulge, almost giving me a thigh gap.

The bulge makes my lower pelvis almost the same width as between my armpits, which is not exactly the most attractive trait.

My current exercise regimen focuses on pecs with pushups, abs with plank+crunches, obliques with side planks, lats with elbow press (Don't have a pull-up bar) and legs with lunges.

I would also like to clarify that I have barely started training, and therefore am still quite weak. I am Asian and 15 3/4 in age.

My question is, which exercises should I focus on to hide this problematic bone bulge?
[image: Greater Trochanter of the femur is the bulge]

Comment: How tall are you and how much do you weight? Perhaps you just need more muscle around the bones?

Comment: 6 feet, 139 pounds
I don't think the hip part is a muscle thing; my hip shape is frankly very abnormal whenever I look at it.

Comment: To be honest my thinness might be partially genetic; most of my father's side of my family is quite thin. My half-brother (24) is very fit (in terms of musculature and general strength) but he's as thin as me measuring by mass.

Comment: The hip part is not a muscle thing, but being thin makes bones more evident. Muscle and fat are what you can use to change your body shape in general, making these bones less obvious.

Comment: I see. Where should I try to build muscle to more effectively hide this issue? If I build on my hips it would just make the bulge more obvious relative to the rest of my body.

Answer (score 4):

#### Just gain some weight.

139 lbs at 6'0" is a BMI of 18.8, which borders on underweight according to most standards. Your bones stick out because you're skinny. Just gain some weight and this will likely go away. See this answer for detailed guidance: [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)