# Good diet plan for 16 yr old active boy (carbs and protein)

Tags: diet

Recently I have been wanting to get more in shape, and I was always pretty fit. However doing a lot of research, I noticed I only do exercises, but in terms of food and dieting I have never even thought twice about it. I now know that proper food is so important, but I don't know what I need to eat, how much to consume, or a diet plan to follow specifically for my abs. Is it true you should eat protein every day? (salmon, beef, lamb, turkey etc)

Comment: I suspect you are really asking ["How do I gain weight and muscle?"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle), but only focusing on one point. That link is a great answer, as well as the link on number 2 goes in great detail for the nutrition side. As a side note, you can't target fat loss for abs. It is just somewhere males accumulate fate naturally. Abs are mostly luck of the draw depending on where the inserts are, and how round the muscle bellies are so don't worry about it if they aren't perfectly symmetrical.