# Why is 40 pushups a day not doing anything?

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, push-ups, biceps

My goal is to build muscle, especially in the arms/biceps.

Originally I was doing about 10 pushups a day along with some bicep stretches (wall stretch, using rollers, deltoid stretch, etc). In mid-June I started doing 25 pushups daily since I wanted to challenge myself (and I realized 10 a day is close to nothing). So, I continued with 25 daily, up until mid-July because I didn't see any noticeable muscle gain. Again, I upped the ante to 40 a day. Now I'm still doing 40 per day but I have yet to see my muscles getting bigger.

Am I being too impatient, or should I keep upping the count? Thanks!

Note: I'm doing a mix of regular on-the-floor pushups and modified pushups, but mostly regulars

Comment: People often underestimate how hard it is to grow muscle. That's where the fear of "getting too big" comes from. Your body doesn't want to put on muscle because it is very metabolically costly. If your body can do the work with the muscle it has, why put on more and needlessly burn extra calories?

Comment: I'm 70. In my early 20s I wanted to more easily pull my motorcycle out of mud holes in the environment I often rode in.  I did 100 pushups a day - sometimes in several griups but I could do 100 at a time. I never seemed to get any better at extricating my motorcycle :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Because for pulling you have to do deadlifts, rowing, pull-ups etc.

Comment: Not a specific answer to this but be careful about doing too many pushups without doing some balancing exercise.  Years ago, I was doing a lot of pushups and it caused a lot of back and neck issues.  Rows with dumbbells and stable stool/ottoman are easy to do at home.

Comment: What everyone else said. But also, don't underestimate the value of resting. Overloading yourself every day is not an effective way to gain muscle. This is why it's actually recommended that you take 1-2 rest days between workouts.

Comment: Do it until you can't do anymore, not until a set number. At least that way you gain strength if not mass.

Comment: Yes, just push the number of pushups you can do in a single streak and you'll see results. Also, though it might be obvious, do not expect your biceps to grow from this, only triceps, which is not so visible. You can measure the circumference in that area to see your progress.

Comment: Look how lean the world-record push-up holder is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_cp5dWpXzY. Push-ups are only difficult up to a certain number, after that you're just working on your endurance. To build muscle with push-ups you need to add weight safely to actually challenge your muscles. I am willing to bet your muscles have more definition than they used to even if they're not bulkier. I would personally move on to other exercises. You are probably strong enough to do chin-ups now.

Comment: I agree with you all - it's important to not overload myself, but at the same time, I think I should try other exercises :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Please check if you are missing something from [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/31261) on how to build muscle. The two most common things people mess up when trying to grow larger muscles are they don't eat enough, and they don't sleep enough. It sounds like you also aren't working hard enough or even the correct muscle groups for your goals.

While 40 pushups is great progress from your starting point, it is simply not enough to build much muscle even with the perfect diet and sleep schedule. Also, pushups build your chest and triceps primarily, try pullups or some form of pulling movement to work on your biceps. As a rule of thumb, pushing away from you works chest, triceps, quads, calves, etc. Pulling works biceps, back, hamstrings, etc. Perhaps try pullups if you have access to a bar?

You need to try to progress a little bit every time you work out, so one more rep or a little more weight. A lot of the time you might not get an extra rep in and that is perfectly normal. The issue with your current routine is simply that your body has gotten used to how much work you are putting in. If your body can handle your current routine, why would it need to produce any more contractile tissue?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that if you insist on doing unweighted push-ups you have to build up to 100s of push-ups every day to see results (1).

Personally I do push-ups with a weight plate on my back instead.
That way I can progress with far fewer repetitions, and only doing push-ups 2 or 3 times a week.

Another option is to switch to dips. They are a lot harder than push-ups but train many of the same muscles.

Also as already mentioned you must make sure that you eat enough and in particular a lot of protein.

And as already mentioned it is important to train your pulling muscles also.
Otherwise you may risk posture like a monkey and pain.
You should do horizontal row exercises pulling shoulder blades together.
Inverted rows (australian pullups) is one good option. Barbell rows or 1 handed dumbell rows is another one.

I would suggest you do one of these two circuits:

**A (eg. outside in a park)**

- 1 set of dips
- 1 set of inverted rows
- 1 set of push-ups
- 1 set of inverted rows

Repeat

**B (in the gym)**

- 1 set of weighted push-ups
- 1 set of barbell rows

Repeat

(1) https://www.thebioneer.com/bodyweight-training/

Comment: Regarding unweighted is too easy: Lots of beginners have bad form when doing push-ups. Simply doing them with perfect form all the way down to the ground and a slow eccentric phase will make them a lot harder. Elevate the feet if it’s still too easy. Do different variations (e.g. typewriter push-ups, diamond push-ups etc.) to target slightly different muscle groups.

Comment: Note that the recommended protein intake for people strength training is not significantly higher than the general protein intake recommendation. https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/002458.htm

Comment: @Vaelus what evidence is this based on?  I thought it was fairly established that one needs to eat a lot of protein spread throughout the day to add muscle?

Comment: @Tom Like the article said, it's a myth. It cites [Position of the Academy of Nutrition and Dietetics, Dietitians of Canada, and the American College of Sports Medicine: Nutrition and Athletic Performance](https://jandonline.org/article/S2212-2672(15)01802-X/fulltext), whivh goes into more details and ccites specific studies. You might also look at the relevant sections of [Dietary Reference Intakes for Energy, Carbohydrate, Fiber, Fat, Fatty Acids, Cholesterol, Protein, and Amino Acids](https://www.nap.edu/read/10490/chapter/12#660).

Comment: @Tom Note also that MedlinePlus is a fairly reliable source for health information, unlike many supposed online sources of health information, since [it is a service of the NIH](https://medlineplus.gov/about/general/aboutmedlineplus/).

Comment: That's interesting as I went from 1g of protein per kilo of bodyweight per day to 2g of protein per kilo of bodyweight per day and seemed to notice a definite improvement in strength and maybe muscle gain as well, but I might be mistaken.  I might try going back to about 1.2g to see what happens or if I lose any strength.

Comment: Also note that a lot of studies mentioned in Position of the Academy are done on time-scales of several weeks and so useless, as it takes years to monitor the most effective way for an individual to build muscle.  This is true of a lot of other studies in the literature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128285/discussion-between-vaelus-and-tom).

Answer (score 4):

##### Number of reps

At 40 reps, you're training for endurance. That's great for toning - but not for putting on bulk. Some answers have suggested using a weight plate on your back. A simpler solution though is simply to support your feet on a chair.

##### Position

Look at how wide your hands are. With wide arms, you're mostly just working your pecs. Standard push-ups for martial arts have the hands immediately below the shoulders to give a more complete workout; hands touching is even harder.

##### Push-ups are not the whole story

I had a similar idea, about 3 years back. What I found was that simply doing push-ups without any corresponding exercise for my back muscles resulted in my pecs pulling my shoulders forward into a "hunch". My pecs may have been toned, but that posture just made them sag. I looked worse, not better.

My solution was to add a workout on my shoulders and back. Nothing excessive - arm raises, rhomboid pulls, and so on. I now have much better posture than I ever remember having before, because my back development has naturally helped to pull my shoulders down and back. If you're about the looks, then this opens your chest up and pushes your pecs out, making you generally look better.

Comment: I don't really buy the endurance thing. By increasing volume, e.g. going up to 60, 80, 100, 120 reps the muscles will be obliged to grow to do that.

Comment: But I totally agree about the final point. Too often people focus on the muscles that they can see in the mirror. For men that's chest, abs, front deltoids (and biceps) — all the muscles that curl you forward and inward making a terrible posture. For pretty much any goal — health, looks, athleticity, ... working on your back is at least as important as the front.

Comment: @Dzuris Muscles develop differently depending on training for endurance with lighter loads, or fewer reps with heavier loads. There's a reason marathon runners and power lifters don't look the same. :)

Answer (score 3):

For reference I started seriously taking my fitness into account Mar 20 and went from this:
[image]

to this:
[image]

Some of my thoughts on my journey:

- To get to the same level of definition that you see on TV, social media, and Hollywood is just not possible for regular people, at least naturally. Those folks have $$$, 6+ hours a day, and a private chef and trainer.
- Even if you have those things it takes a LONG time of CONSISTENT training to get visible results. The two pictures shared was from Jul 19 to Aug 20.
- During that time I was training 2-3 hours a day every single day and averaging anywhere between 300 > 800 reps a day.
- I realize that it's not the number of reps but the efficiency of the progression that matters most. 10 planche push ups with perfect form >>> 100 regular push ups any day.
- I was also fasting (8 eat; 16 fast) and eating purely protein and vegetables. Zero carbs, dairy, or sugar. And I mean zero; maybe one "cheat" meal a month (if even that). A lot of them also dehydrate for the "shot" to get that crazy level of tone.
- Enjoy the process. The best feeling is when you get to a level of consistency that you wake up and look forward to working out. And feel yourself grow stronger and lighter all the while at it.

Hope you stick with it!

Answer (score 1):

I gotta add some information for you:

First of all, doing the same excercise will get your muscles "used" to it. At some point there is a plateau and it takes a lot more time to actually grow.

So variation in your excercise is key, you should switch up ever 6 - 8 weeks.

Also you honestly dont do enough for muscle grow. You really need to do more excercises than "just" push ups. Get some weights honestly. Depending on how much you weigh, weightless training can only do so much for you. As a big feller it does a lot for you, as a lean boy not much at all.

Lastly it is REALLY important to work GROUPS of muscles and the "antigroup". Like dont do JUST biceps, you also need should and lower arms because it looks stupid and you need to support that biceps. You also need to train triceps, so your biceps doesnt become to strong for your triceps and you cant extend your arms anymore.

One last tip, dont forget to stretch, you do it and that is great. Otherwise your muscles will pull together and get short.

Comment: Do you have any scientific reference about getting "used" to it? I am under the impression that the current science doesn't believe that. It's just total volume and good rest that counts.

Comment: https://theconversation.com/health-check-do-we-lose-gains-from-exercise-as-our-bodies-get-used-to-it-82311#:~:text=Our%20bones%2C%20muscles%2C%20tendons%2C,a%20blessing%20and%20a%20curse.

There you go. There is literally loads of information about your system getting "used" to certain workout. And why shouldnt it? From a evolutionary standpoint it totally makes sense that doing the same work over and over again stops becoming tiring and stops making you "heavy" with muscles. 
You get stronger, yes, but muscle grow stops.

Comment: The article that you linked is not a scientific publication and it doesn't even argue for switching exercises, it just tells to increase the amount/intensity.

Comment: @bibleblade - This site is based on gathering answers that are sourced in scientific research. Don't get upset and start namecalling when someone asks to see the research that backs up your claims.