# Pain after push ups and plank

Tags: push-ups, back-pain, planks

I am feeling pain in my upper back after doing push ups and planks in a same day. Pain is there from last 2 days. I don't know what causes pain in my upper back.

Is bad form cause pain or overdoing the exercises cause pain ?

Is it better to do light warm up back exercises ? Or taking pain relievers and taking bed rest ?

Update :

Height : 6.1
Weight : 71  kg ( approximate )
Age : 30
Pain : below right shoulder blade,
I started workout after long time , I am beginner
How much i did :
Push ups : 6 * 5
Plank : 1 min , 3 times
I took pain killer paracetamol now.

Comment: There needs to be a bit more information for anyone to actually help you. How old are you, what is your weight and height, how long have you been working out, how many times per week? Does the 'pain' feel like soreness or something different? Where in the upper back? Around the spine, shoulder blades, lats, traps? How many reps, and how long did you do the plank? Give us as much relevant information as you can so we can narrow down the massive number of things this might be.

Comment: Would likely need a video, too.

Comment: @EricWarburton updated question

Comment: If I were to guess, you injured yourself due to poor form. When you first start out, it is pretty common for people to lift more weight than they should and as a result they resort to poor form to make the movement easier. In the gym it is better to drop the ego and lift what you can, and if that means doing knee pushups until you build up the strength, then do it. For now, try letting the injured muscle rest, and if it is still bad in a week or so, you should see a doctor. It is impossible for people on the internet to diagnose this stuff, so the best we can do is guess.

Comment: @EricWarburton I am doing workout in home only, okay I will start with knee push-up only....  I will check some videos , then follow them.... But it's difficult to identify how much workout is enough for me.... How much muscle building exercise I should do? How much cardio I should do,? Everytime when I workout bit more time, I end up getting pain .

Comment: If something is hurting, stop working it out until it stops hurting. Listen to your body. Find someone that can critique your form so you don't injure yourself. Perhaps post a form check here with a video and we can try to help your form. As for how much of anything you should do will depend on your goals. What are you trying to accomplish by working out?

Comment: @EricWarburton there is no proper gym and instructors In the area where I am living, it's village, I will join gym once i move to city. I  wanna be actor, so I want some good looking posture and muscles..... I hope 6 months workout is enough to get that.....

Comment: You should probably read [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/31261). It details exactly what you need to do to get a good physique. Just be aware that building muscle takes years of hard work, and you won't get results overnight.

Comment: Upper back pain form push ups and planks feels odd and uncommon. You should get it check by a physio first. Does doing a push up now make the pain worse? Sharp pain, dull ache, what kind of pain? What actions will cause this pain to worsen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should do these exercises in proper position and you may not need warmup cause these are already warmup exercises done in gym before weight training. If you are new to workout or have not done since a long time then maybe a bit of `hand-rolling` and `shoulder blades squeezing` can help your nervous system to be active.
Now coming to the main part, these exercises are meant to cause squeeze in your traps(minor squeeze) and rhomboids(major squeeze).
So now in your case it could be one of the following reasons:-

1. Your older age and not doing warmup.
2. Not placing your hands and holding your abdominal area in proper position.
3. Overdoing the exercises, as compared to your daily workout intensity.
4. You maybe weak in your upper back region cause you have never exercised that area.
5. You are over-weight and have done too much push-ups, according to your back strength.(Yes over-weight people can do push-ups too if they have that back and triceps muscles).
6. Or the least occuring factor that is, your poor nutrition, cause of that your tore muscles aren't repaired.

As by your body weight and height it seems that your are bit under-weight and your nutrition is not good that's the reason you are feeling muscle pain even after doing so less number of reps and sets and if it's under shoulder blades that means it's muscle soreness.

I suggest you to watch these videos to better understand your problem.
[The Official Push-Up Checklist (AVOID MISTAKES!)](https://youtu.be/-Mbr55h3BeQ)
[Bodyweight Back Workout](https://youtu.be/mjnseqLiVXM)
[All About Traps (COMPLETE GROWTH GUIDE!)](https://youtu.be/eqYNJLbxRkk)
[Mid Back Stretch and Rhomboid Release (HOW TO TARGET THIS!)](https://youtu.be/dNOMmQARQTQ)
I suggest you to subscribe this man he is great in this field.