# Does the often you exercise, the higher calorie intake need to gain weight and muscles?

Tags: exercise, diet, workout, nutrition, calories

I'm a hardgainer and my genetics makes me skinny. I want to get bulk and have muscle but the being a poor young asian guy hinders me to eat good foods. I cant afford mass gainers nor whey protein, I always eat dishes with huge amount rice, and that is where I get calories. I eat 5 times a day. I started working out every day for a year and have a little progress, I dont aim to be jack or muscular, I just want to bulk. Do I need to reduce my workout routine and just workout 3-4 times a week with the same 5 time a day eating routine so I can bulk? My total calorie intake range from 1800-2200 (260 calorie of rice and about 100-300 calorie dish per meal)

Comment: How tall are you, and how much do you weigh?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

Comment: And what's your current training like?