# Are there any good exercises to make pectus carinatum less noticeable and exercises that can help get rid of rib flare

Tags: exercise, muscle-gain, chest, growth, motivation

I am 14 years old, 5'7, and weighed 118 last time I checked. One side of my sternum protrudes more than the other side leading me to believe I have pectus carinatum. [image]

It's noticeable even from the front view if under a light. I think this is mild PC but I'm only 14 and I read online that it can get worse with age so I want to prevent that and also hide it a bit as well, so if anyone has exercises that can do this please tell me. I also have rib flare as you can see from the image, and I would like to know how to get rid of it. I already do some exercising at a taekwondo place 3 times a week, but it's not enough to build that much muscle and solve my PC and rib flares. I am still young so hopefully, I can do something about this before it's too late. None of my friends know about this since I try to hide it with clothes that are black or thick to make it less noticeable. I used to be depressed and had very poor hygiene neglecting to shower and take care of myself, and now I regret all of it and am trying to fix all my bad habits and problems to build confidence. I want to build confidence so I can get into a relationship and do more fun things with my friends like going to the pool without being judged. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

#### You just need to gain some weight.

You have a BMI of 18.5. You could stand to gain 40 pounds and your BMI would stay in the healthy range of "less than 25", especially if a good portion of that weight gain was lean mass. Just follow the advice of [this fitness.se answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/34721):

> To gain good weight, to bulk, to add muscle, you need to:
>
> - Stimulate growth by lifting heavy
> - Provide fuel for growth by eating a lot
> - Prioritize your goal by getting your life in order
>
> Most healthy people who do these things gain weight. Mostly muscle.

The answer goes into greater detail about these steps, but this is the most straightforward solution to your issue. There are no magic exercises for your problem.

Comment: Ok I will try to bulk