Any advice for a really skinny 20 y/o male beginner looking to bulk up quick?
I’m about 6’2 at 145-150 lbs (30” waist with very little fat). I’ve been underweight my whole life and I’m sick of it. I do believe I have a faster than average metabolism, as I’ve counted calories for a while now and my maintenance seems to be at about 2500 while sitting around all day.
Recently, I’ve begun serious weight training for the first time. I don’t wanna lay out my whole routine because I change up the exercises a lot just trying to experiment and build good form, but I’m doing full body 3x a week plus one day targeting whichever muscle groups I feel have recovered. I’m relatively strong for my size, being able to do 135x5 on bench and crank out dumbbell curls with 30s as a beginner, so at least I have something to work with.
On the nutrition side of things, I upped the calories to 4000. My diet isn’t super dirty, as I don’t eat a ton of greasy fast food, but about half of my calories come from protein shakes, ice cream, peanut butter, etc. Protein intake is moderate, carbs high, fat high. I know a 1000 calorie surplus is excessive, but I want to be in the 180 lb range ASAP, even if it means an increase in body fat. Being super skinny is one of the worst feelings ever as a young guy, and I just wanna be rid of it.
I think 6 months is a realistic time frame to for me to get a slim/average build. Any guidance or advice would be appreciated.

How much protein are you actually getting?

@ThomasMarkov 100g on a bad day, 150+ on a good day, so like probably around 130g, which should be fine for someone my size based on the research that I’ve read.

Yeah, that’s plenty given your body mass.

Are you sleeping enough? https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771 And – I don't know how to ask this, so — are you trying hard in the gym? I don't mean "do you get sweaty and tired" but do you challenge yourself on heavy lifts. "Experimenting" sounds like it could be fuckarounditis.

@DaveLiepmann Yes, I sleep 8 hours a night minimum. Also, by experimenting, I mean just trying different exercises. For each set I go for at least 8 reps as heavy as I can (except on certain movements like bench), and I do sets until I physically cannot move the weight anymore, then I  rest and transition to doing something else. I do this until each muscle group is totally fatigued.

You have a lot of vagueness in your question. How are you tracking calories? How are you tracking your macro breakdowns? Do you account for everything, and I mean everything that you intake? Do you keep a food diary? What do you mean by "sitting around", do you go to school? Work? Or literally just sit on the couch all day? For your height/weight, assuming 25 y/o male you burn 1700 cals for BMR and abt 800 calories for a desk job, so 2500 a day is not a "fast" metabolism.

And as @DaveLiepmann notices, your experimenting is not really an ideal approach. I would look at a solid beginner program such as Stronglifts 5x5 or similar. While I can appreciate not wanting to look skinny, unless you just pack on fat which you will want to lose later, train sensibly and be patient.

@JohnP I was being vague because I’m looking for clear guidance. Most public fitness information is either bro science or geared towards fat people. I track calories daily on a whiteboard and average the week’s worth. The 2500 figure is from sitting at a desk playing video games and doing zero exercise all summer, and I gained/lost 0 pounds in this time frame. For my stats/activity during this time, certain calculators have suggested my TDEE to be around 2100, so I would say my metabolism is decently fast. Also, I actually WANT to gain fat, because my frame is so lanky and lean as it is.

@JohnP thanks though, I’ll look into that routine. I’m just trying to find one that I’m confident I can stick to.

If you sit around playing video games, you are still burning energy. A small sample of studies indicate you can burn in the neighborhood of 150-200 calories per hour doing so. So, if you play video games for 3 hours, you're burning 450-600 calories.

The reason I'm sort of hammering on this, is that vagueness just won't work and won't produce the results you want. I expect you are both expending more calories than you think and eating more than you think.

You’re probably right. But most people tell skinny guys they eat LESS than they think, so that’s interesting. I wouldn’t think that gaming burns many calories, although I do have days where I’m exerting full focus on a PC game for 6 hours at a time, so possibly.

How old are you? That will also affect substantially your results.

@Luciano I’m 20

I think you need to narrow down to what the question is, because it's very broad now.
That being said;
What I can tell you is that you should take into consideration that it will take up to 2 years to have big results. 6 months is a very short time for significant muscle growth, although you will see improvements quickly when you first start out.
I started out the same way you did, being below 60kg in bodyweight at 6ft tall. I grew about 18-20kg of bodyweight in the first 2-3 years, without gaining much fat (always staying around or below 10% bodyfat, so most of that was muscle mass). This low bodyfat % is simply due to my genetics, I didn't try to stay lean, it just happened. I ate everything I could, going over 4000cal per day just like you.
If you want to be serious about gaining muscle mass, you should train every muscle group twice a week rather than once, because recovery after a workout is much shorter than a full week, usually 2 days of recovery per muscle group is fine.
Training higher rep ranges with lower weight is also adviced, simply due to the fact that it's a safer way to train. You will run into less injuries this way, which means you can continue to train and reach your goals. I would suggest rep ranges of 8 on compounds lifts, up to 12 on isolation movements. If you really want to become strong too, doing sets of 3 or 5 on compound lifts is more beneficial.
While training, really focus on how the movement is supposed to be performed. It's not about the fact that the weight moves from point A to point B, but rather how it gets from point A to point B. Keeping your upper farm still throughout a bicep curl rather than swinging from the shoulder, is a prime example of this.
I would also suggest supplementing creatine, this probably is by far the best supplement you can take to boost you workouts, and thus your muscle growth.

Thanks for the advice, this was sort of how I was training already. Lots of conflicting info on whether you should focus on high reps or low reps starting out though. Also, I’m NOT trying to build an enormous amount of muscle in such a short time frame. I’d be more than happy to gain 10 pounds of muscle plus 20 pounds of fat/water/etc. The goal right now is just to look a little more filled out, not to become an athlete. With such an energy surplus I believe that this is realistic, but maybe I’m like you and it’ll take a little while longer because I stay lean.

When it comes to rep ranges, I personally implement both; low reps and high weight on compound lifts, and high reps lower weight on isolation movements. For example, I'll bench 5 sets of 5 reps with relatively high weight, and then I'll do chest fly for 3 sets of 12 reps, with lower weight. This way you have best of both worlds. I was mainly suggesting high rep ranges with lower weight because I saw the tag beginner, and for beginners it's safer to start with these rep ranges

+1 for recommending creatine alone, any other supplement is very much secondary until there's a problem to be addressed

Take some weight gainer, because you are not getting enough calories.
The picture below was taken by me with my son, 1 year apart:

I got him that size by making him a weight gainer drink every morning for breakfast.
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089B6KCTR/
I'm not trying to advertise on here, but the Ronny Coleman brand in the link above is what I have been feeding him.

Thanks, I use optimum nutrition’s brand of mass gainer. My calories are fine I believe, as I’m already up 5 pounds in a month after accounting for food/water weight. Currently I’m eating 3500-4000 calories a day. I started with 4000 but that was a little bit overkill.
